# xcodebuild does not show output from OSLog in debug level

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodebuild, oslog

I am using `xcodebuild` to test my application in CI. I invoke it like this:

```
xcodebuild test -project myapp.xcodeproj -scheme myappTests -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=14.4'
```

Text logged with the `Logger` from `OSLog` are not shown in debug level. So if I have something like this in my test, it isn't shown in the output of `xcodebuild`, but I would like to see that:

```
Logger(subsystem: "a", category: "b").debug("something")
```

Can I set the logging level of `xcodebuild` to debug? Messages with error level are shown.

I tried setting `xcodebuildDebugLogLevel=3` but that gave me the same logging information.

Answer (score 2):

Logger doesn't print `debug` (and `trace`) messages to the output because a log level of your subsystem on your simulator is `INFO`.

You can check this with next steps:

1. Find your simulator UDID that you use for tests:

```sh
$ xcrun simctl list
...
-- iOS 15.2 --
    iPhone 8 (C1D16369-D358-438E-8395-D01C2DE55980) (Shutdown) 
...
```

2. Boot it if needed

```sh
$ xcrun simctl boot C1D16369-D358-438E-8395-D01C2DE55980
```

3. Check a log level of your subsystem name:

```sh
$ xcrun simctl spawn C1D16369-D358-438E-8395-D01C2DE55980 log config --subsystem <your-subsystem-name> --status
Mode for '<your-subsystem-name>'  INFO PERSIST_DEFAULT
```

To change the current log level to `DEBUG` you can use next command:

```sh
$xcrun simctl spawn C1D16369-D358-438E-8395-D01C2DE55980 log config --subsystem <your-subsystem-name> --mode level:debug
```

Check again:

```sh
xcrun simctl spawn C1D16369-D358-438E-8395-D01C2DE55980 log config --subsystem <your-subsystem-name> --status 
Mode for '<your-subsystem-name>'  DEBUG PERSIST_DEFAULT
```

Now your tests with `xcodebuild` must have all debug (and trace) messages in the output.

> Note: Console.app doesn't provide debug/trace messages even after changes from abobe and it's old known issue with simulators.

Comment: What should I substitute with <your-subsystem-name>? When I fill in the subsystem of the value which I create the Logger with, I get this terminal error: An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
No such file or directory

Comment: @J.Doe Usually <your-subsystem-name> should be in reverse DNS notation, such as com.your_company.your_subsystem_name. Which command fails?